# Can't access to array once I sorted it

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I sorted. Now once I want to iterate that array I get "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool"

```
      $myArray = array(10, 3, 4, 1, 7);
      $newArray = sort($myArray);

      echo $newArray[0];  // Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

      for($i = 0; $i < count($newArray ); $i++){
           echo $newArray [$i]; //Trying to access array offset on value of type bool
      }
```

Why is this happening.

if I do not sort it it works fine. How can I solve this issue

```
      $myArray = array(10, 3, 4, 1, 7);

      for($i = 0; $i < count($myArray ); $i++){
           echo $myArray [$i]; 
      }
```

Comment: sort takes the array by reference and sorts it. It doesn't return the sorted array.

Comment: It only returns true or false. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php#refsect1-function.sort-returnvalues